# Matlab and Python for Mathematics

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

What are the most used Matlab and python libraries used in Calculus and Analysis? At the moment I'm reading a book on Real Analysis and I thought that interactive tools would help me to better understand it and study practical examples.

Comment: *Mathematica*..

Comment: Neither calculus nor analysis requires a computer.

Comment: @John Douma They do not **require** a computer stricto sensu but **in the process of learning** it can help a lot, especially students who are not majoring in mathematics. Beginning by free software like Geogebra or Desmos, for the end of high school and first years of undergraduate studies with which you can do didactic marvels...

Comment: As you ask about libraries in Matlab in particular, I only know well the **image processing toolbox** that I strongly advise you.

Comment: @JohnDouma Belive in calculus, not in calculators ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's many possibilities:

Matlab, Mathematica, Maple have essentially everything you could need built-in.

Desmos has really nice online graphing capabilities.

For more variability/options can use Python or my preferred choice Julia.

For Python, it has the math module and can use libraries such as numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib.

In Julia, theres nice libraries (packages) such as LinearAlgebra.jl, DifferentialEquations.jl, etc.

If you are attending university, your school may have a licence for you to use mathematica or maple free of cost.

EDIT: I had forgotten, there is also Sage that can be used.